# Can't load RemObjects.InternetPack under Mono

Tags: linux, mono, delphi-prism, oxygene

I wrote a program on Windows 7 with Delphi Prism. I took the executable and try to run it on Linux under mono. At which point, mono raised the following error. Is this mean RemObjects components are only meant for windows environment? If not, how do you resolve this exception?

**Could not load file or assembly 'RemObjects.InternetPack, Version=2.0.47.845, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3df3cad1b7aa5098' or one of its dependencies.
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.**

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you install `RemObjects.InternetPack` on Linux? It doesn't exist by default; it's installed as part of Prism on Windows, and would have to be distributed (and registered) with your app on Mono/Linux.

Comment: @KenWhite Oh I see. well, I didn't know you have to install and register it for linux/mono too. I thought when you compiled your prism application on windows, it will automatically link or carry over the essential functions by default when you run your prism application under mono.

Comment: No. It's like compiling a Win32 Delphi app with run-time packages. When you deploy the application to another machine, you have to deploy the runtime packages also; they don't just magically appear. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to deploy and register `RemObjects InternetPack` on the Linux machine. It's not part of the default runtime.

Think of it like building a `Delphi Win32` app with runtime packages. When you deploy the application to other machines, you also have to deploy the runtime packages.

Deploying `.NET` packages is a totally different question (and not really `Delphi` or `Prism` related). You might want to search here on SO first, and if you don't find an existing answer then post a new question.

Comment: I solved this issue by taking RemObjects.InternetPack.dll from windows and putting in root: user/lib/mono/4.0/ on Linux. I am pretty sure there is more informal way of deploying RemObjects to Linux for mono maybe through a script or something.